# Como defino certos valores de um array para um mesmo valor? (Java)

Tags: java, array

Exemplo, eu tenho um array de duas dimensões do tipo int:

```
int array[][] = new int[10][10];
```

Como eu defino o valor de, por exemplo [2][3], [6][7] e [1][9] para algum mesmo int, sem precisar definir um de cada vez assim:

```
array[2][3] = -1;
array[6][7] = -1;
array[1][9] = -1;
```

Comment: porque você precisa fazer isso? o que está implementando?

Answer (score 1):

De algum modo vc precisará informas as posições específicas em que deseja o mesmo valor. Assim, uma otimização pequena seria desta maneira.

```
 array[2][3] =  array[6][7] =  array[1][9] = -1;
```